How to handle an `IAsyncEnumerable` fully concurrently? Is `Parallel.ForEachAsync` the answer?
Imagine I have an IAsyncEnumerable<Request> where each Request represents some kind of incoming message that I want to handle, but I don't want to wait for each message handler to finish before moving on to the next iteration/message; I want as many as messages as possible to be handled "concurrently".
Can I use the simple overload of the Parallel.ForEachAsync method (without a max thread count specified, so as to delegate the handling of all of that to the framework itself)?
Basically, I don't want this:
await foreach (var request in requests) // `requests` is an `IAsyncEnumerable<Request>`
{
    await Handle(request); // I don't want to await here
}

Would it be sound to do this instead? Or is this problematic (could potentially exhaust the thread pool or overwhelm system resources, for example)? Or is there somehow a better approach?
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(requests, async (request, ct) =>
{
    await Handle(request);
});

Update: Parallel.ForEachAsync seems like a bad option because it caps the number of parallel handler invocations to the number of the host machine's CPU cores.

Parallel.ForEachAsync is indeed the simplest inbuilt mechanism to do what you want; if you want to stop the concurrency going too wild, ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism achieves that. Note that if you don't actively need to await the completion of everything, you could also just await foreach and Task.Run (or similar) the individual requests.

Other options you might want to consider that change the route in:
a) Channel as a producer/consumer queue (potentially multi-producer, multi-consumer, depending on options), allowing for bounding at the producer side
b) simply using Task.Run at the side of incoming requests

@Charlieface This is absolutely not a "duplicate" of the questions you linked to; those are asking about Task & async/await specifically, this one's a higher-level question. I have no idea what you're on about. If the obviously-loose association between my question and those linked is sufficient for the former to be deemed as a "duplicate", then every question ever asked by any human being since Aristotle has been a "duplicate". Come on.

@MarcGravell don't forget Dataflow.

I'm confused: it looks to me that you are asking about whether the bit async (request, ct) => { await Handle(request); } can be elided into (request, ct) => { return Handle(request); } which exactly what those duplicates talk about. Parallel.ForEachAsync seems irrelevant to the overall question about whether await can be elided. If that's not the case then please explain, I'm happy to reopen it if I've misunderstood.

@Charlieface That's not what I'm asking at all. What I wanted to know was how to parallelize IAsyncEnumerable iterations to get the highest possible throughput when you don't need the iterations to run sequentially. I didn't even hint at async () => await Func() vs () => Func().

I see, sorry. Perhaps this link then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447990/actual-maximum-concurrent-tasks-of-parallel-foreachasync Parallel.ForEachAsync automatically throttles based on number of threadpool threads, and is only problematic if the func is not actually async (say it does a complete block).

seems like a bad option because it caps no it doesn't. It will use as many worker tasks as you tell it. If you want to set MaxDOP to 100 on a 12-core machine, it will use 100 worker tasks even if that leads to thrashing. It will try to avoid nuking the core, which is what the linked question talks about. The default is to use as many worker tasks as there are cores (even virtual). On a 12-core CPU with HT you get 24 concurrent worker tasks

@PanagiotisKanavos The whole point is that I don't want to have to hard-code a hard upper limit; I want things to behave how ASP.NET Core does, for example, where the developer isn't the one setting a max number for concurrent requests, the server handles as much as it can. That's the kind of thing I'm looking for.

how ASP.NET Core does ASP.NET Core, or rather IIS, also handles misbehaved requests, by terminating them or recycling. What is the actual question here? What does Handle actually do? You can't perform any CPU-bound work if all CPU cores are busy. If you have async operations, the threadpool threads will be released to process other requests.

@PanagiotisKanavos Handle performs I/O bound operations, primarily. If I await the returned task, that effectively limits throughput to one request handled at a time, which is what I DON'AT want, the question is how do I lift that limitation in a sound manner? I want maximum concurrency/throughput.

@PanagiotisKanavos Following through from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/91939711895b6141e1be509ee743a8afb7a64ee7/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.ForEachAsync.cs#L390 gives you dop as DefaultDegreeOfParallelism => Environment.ProcessorCount so that's the default maximum number of concurrent requests.

@Charlieface Environment.ProcessorCount takes hyperthreading into account so on a 8-core HT you get 16 tasks. This isn't bad. If the code is written carefully you can actually get 50% better performance over the physical core count.

@Arad you need to explain what the actual scenario is. await doesn't block, it's a way to specify that the code following that statement is the continuation of the asynchronous method. That doesn't mean you can just fire off 100 disk or network operations because the disk or API or database will get into trouble, as concurrent calls start interfering with each other. That's why APIs and web sites throttle requests. Even if you want to eg scrape 100 sites, your network card may have limits, or the ISP's latency can harm throughput

@Arad it may not even be a hardware issue. Years ago I used similar code to poll 2000 remote machines for a customer until ... the customer's network security (a different department) came calling. You can set MaxDegreeOfParallelism to a ridiculous number ,eg 1000, but that doesn't mean you'll get better throughput.

could potentially exhaust the thread pool or overwhelm system resources, for example and the server handles as much as it can are somewhat contradictory requirements. Pushing the envelope for the latter is, almost by design, putting you at risk of the former.
